# symfony mime error trying to upload image in crud form in laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, upload, crud

I'm working on a laravel7 project

i want to make a simple crud, no auth, with a one to many relationship and one of the element of the form is an image.

The problem is that i tried using various solutions i found online searching fo laravel image crud examples but i keep haveing this error when i try to create a product with an image as input:

```
Symfony Exception

LogicException

Unable to guess the MIME type as no guessers are available (have you enabled the php_fileinfo extension?).

  if (!$this->isGuesserSupported()) {            
     throw new LogicException('Unable to guess the MIME type as no guessers are available (have you 
    enabled the php_fileinfo extension?).');        
}
```

- i made the folder images in public
- i tried enabling phpfile info in my php system files

Nothing works. any help? i am 6 months old as a developer so i apologize if asking dumb questions

classes:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Color extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [

        'namecol',
        'imgcol',

    ];

    public function products() {

        return $this -> hasMany(Product::class);
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [

        'namepro',
        'imgpro',

    ];

    public function color() {

        return $this -> belongsTo(Color::class);
    }
}
```

MIGRATIONS:

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('colors', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table -> id();

            $table -> string('namecol', 100) -> unique();
            $table -> string('imgcol') -> nullable();

            $table -> timestamps();
        });
    }


    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('colors');
    }
```

```
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table -> id();

            $table -> string('namepro', 100);
            $table -> string('imgpro') -> nullable();

            $table -> bigInteger('color_id') -> unsigned();
            
            $table -> timestamps();
        }); 
    }

 
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('products');
    }
```

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table -> foreign('color_id', 'product-color')
                    -> references('id')
                    -> on('colors');

        });
    }


    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign('product-color');
        });
    }
```

CREATE AND STORE OF PRODUCT

```
    public function create() {

        $colors = Color::all();
        return view('pages.product-create', compact('colors'));
    }

    public function store(Request $request) {

        $data = $request -> all();


        $request->validate([
            'namepro' => 'required|min:3|max:100',
            'imgpro' => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg,gif,svg|max:2048',

        ]);

        $path = $request->file('imgpro')->store('public/images');
        $product = new Product;
        $product->namepro = $request->namepro;
        $product->imgpro = $path;



        $color = Color::findOrFail($data['color_id']);
        $product = Product::make($request -> all());
        $product -> color() -> associate($color);
        $product -> save();

        
        return redirect() -> route('product-show', $product -> id);
    }
```

FORM IN VIEW

```
    <form action="{{ route('product-store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
        @csrf
        @method('POST')

        <label for="namepro">namepro</label>
        <input name="namepro" type="text">
        <br>

        <label for="imgpro">imgpro</label>
        <input name="imgpro" type="file">
        <br>


        <label for="color_id">color</label>
        <select name="color_id">
            @foreach ($colors as $color)
                <option value="{{ $color -> id }}">

                    {{$color -> namecol}}

                </option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
        <br>



        <input type="submit">

    </form>
```

Comment: have you enabled the php_fileinfo extension?

Comment: i tried that road but i had the same error.

Then after your answer i tried again,

Comment: With <?php phpinfo() ?> i found php ini

Loaded Configuration File C:\MAMP\bin\php\php7.4.1\php.ini

 and i enabled the line: extension=fileinfo   

 i didnt have extension=php_fileinfo 

Now backend works but in front end i have a validation error.

in the form i have as you can see in the code above
```
enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
```

and in the validator i have 

```
 'imgpro' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',

```
Without mimes:etc, same error